# printing results in one line separated by commas in bash

Tags: bash

How can I print all text file location separated by commas in one line? Can I do this in for loop?

Here is an example of files.

```
/data/home/files/txt_files_1/file1.txt
/data/home/files/txt_files_1/file2.txt
/data/home/files/txt_files_1/file3.txt

/data/home/files/txt_files_2/file1.txt
/data/home/files/txt_files_2/file2.txt
/data/home/files/txt_files_2/file3.txt
```

output would look like

```
/data/home/files/txt_files_1/file1.txt,/data/home/files/txt_files_1/file2.txt,/data/home/files/txt_files_1/file3.txt \

/data/home/files/txt_files_2/file1.txt,/data/home/files/txt_files_2/file2.txt,/data/home/files/txt_files_2/file3.txt
```

Thanks

Here is the correct code

```
#!/bin/bash
delim=""
  for i in /data/home/files/txt_files_1/file*
  do
      printf "%s%s" "$delim" "$i"
      delim=","
  done
   printf "\\"
   printf "\n"


  for i in /data/home/files/txt_files_2/file*
  do
      printf "%s%s" "$delim" "$i"
      delim=","
  done
```

Comment: is this information are stored in a single text file?

Comment: You should tell if input is stored in a single file or from multiple files..

Comment: @AvinashRaj these files are in two different folders which are txt_files_1 and txt_files_2. output will b stored in same file

Answer (score 2):

For single file input:

```
awk -v OFS=, -v RS= 'NF { $1 = $1; print }' file
```

Output:

```
/data/home/files/txt_files_1/file1.txt,/data/home/files/txt_files_1/file2.txt,/data/home/files/txt_files_1/file3.txt
/data/home/files/txt_files_2/file1.txt,/data/home/files/txt_files_2/file2.txt,/data/home/files/txt_files_2/file3.txt
```

Or

```
awk -v OFS=, -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' 'NF { $1 = $1; print }' file
```

Output:

```
/data/home/files/txt_files_1/file1.txt,/data/home/files/txt_files_1/file2.txt,/data/home/files/txt_files_1/file3.txt

/data/home/files/txt_files_2/file1.txt,/data/home/files/txt_files_2/file2.txt,/data/home/files/txt_files_2/file3.txt
```

Comment: In the question, the first line of the output ends with a backslash, whereas yours does not.

Comment: @TomFenech I'm hoping it's just an encoding mistake by the OP. There's also no sense adding backslash before an empty line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `printf "%s," "$file"` to print several names into a single line. To get the delimiters right, I use this trick:

```
delim=""
...loop...
    printf "%s%s" "$delim" "$file"
    delim=","
printf "\n"
```

Comment: I have tried your code but it doesn't give the required results. I will write the code and its output under my question

Comment: I have edited your code and now I am getting the required results. Please see above

Answer (score 1):

```
<command to generate lines of paths> | tr '\n' ','
```

example:

```
echo "/data/home/files/txt_files_1/file1.txt
/data/home/files/txt_files_1/file2.txt
/data/home/files/txt_files_1/file3.txt

/data/home/files/txt_files_2/file1.txt
/data/home/files/txt_files_2/file2.txt" | tr '\n' ','
```

outputs:

```
/data/home/files/txt_files_1/file1.txt,/data/home/files/txt_files_1/file2.txt,/data/home/files/txt_files_1/file3.txt,,/data/home/files/txt_files_2/file1.txt,/data/home/files/txt_files_2/file2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input is in a file called `list`, this Perl one-liner does the job:

```
perl -F'\n' -00 -ane 'push @a, join(",", @F) }{ print(join(" \\\n\n", @a), "\n")' list
```

#### explanation

- `-00`, in combination with `-n`, reads the file one block (paragraph) at a time.
- The `-a` switch in combination with `-F'\n'` auto-splits the text on each new line. The result goes into the array `@F`.
- An array is built, each element containing the comma separated list of the elements in `@F`
- Once the file has been processed, all the elements of the array `@a` are printed, joined together as you specified. The additional "\n" on the end is optional.

Output:

```
/data/home/files/txt_files_1/file1.txt,/data/home/files/txt_files_1/file2.txt,/data/home/files/txt_files_1/file3.txt \

/data/home/files/txt_files_2/file1.txt,/data/home/files/txt_files_2/file2.txt,/data/home/files/txt_files_2/file3.txt
```